# Print 1 to N - Digits Count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a question in a coding website and got some problem in solving it. The question is:

> Print 1 to N - Digits Count [ZOHO]
>
> A positive integer N is passed as the input. If we print all the
>   numbers from 1 to N continuosly, the program must find the number of
>   characters(digits) C printed and print the count C as the output.
>
> Input Format: The first line contains N.
>
> Output Format: The first line contains C.
>
> Boundary Conditions: 1 <= N <= 9999999
>
> Example Input/Output 1: Input: 2
>
> Output: 2
>
> Explanation: We print 12 and hence the total number of characters is
>   2.
>
> Example Input/Output 2: Input: 15
>
> Output: 21
>
> Explanation: We print 123456789101112131415 and hence the total number
>   of characters is 21.

I solved the problem, but my code didn't pass all the test cases (they are hidden). This is my code:

```
n = int(input())
assert 1<=n<=9999999
a = [str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
b = ''.join(a)
print(len(b))
```

Is this is the right way to solve the problem or is there any other way which can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a time or memory limit you're hitting? `print(sum(len(str(i)) for for i in range(1,n+1)))` would take care of the memory limit, but it'll still take a while to run. There are faster ways of computing the total length.

Comment: @Blender: there seems to be an extra `for` in your sample.

Comment: @Rama Krishna, I suppose that the test fails because your code isn't fast enough.

Comment: Note that for 1 through 9, you can return 1 since the result is a single digit. Can you find a pattern that will allow you to calculate the answer without actually creating the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a *Math* question, I would preferably use a more mathematical approach as it would use much less memory and will be much more efficient.

Here is my approach.

> 1. Calculate the length of the number.
>
>    - If `length = 1`, you are guaranteed to have `9x1` characters.
>    - If `length = 2`, you are guaranteed to have `9x1 + 90x2` characters.
>    - If `length = 3`, you are guaranteed to have `9x1 + 90x2 + 900x3` characters and so on...
>
>    I hope you can see a *loop* forming here.
> 2. For the rest part, take an example of `1234`, `1234 - 1000 = 234` numbers will have *length = length of the number*. No, Mistake : 234
>      +1 = 235 numbers will have *length = length of the number* !

Formulating it in a code.

```
n = input()
length = len(n)
x,s = 9,0
for i in range(1,length):
    s=s+x*i
    x = x*10 # 9-> 90-> 900->
print(s+(int(n)-10**(length-1)+1)*length) # 234 + 1
#         1234 - 10^3
#            = 234            +1
#                          = 235 * 4(length) = ...
```

---

```
>>> 1234
3829
>>>> 15
21
```

I also did `import time` to see efficiency. For `n=9999999`, your code took about **3.26 sec**, while this one takes about **160-200 usec**.

Comment: I think I found a faster answer, will try it and answer if I manage to get it

Comment: @Adirio Do answer. I would like to have a look.

Comment: I will, but I'm testing a second method. I'm getting results in the order of tenths of us

Comment: My methods seems to be a couple us slower than yours, which is taking 1/10 of what you  are using.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm also working on a no-loop version, but it still takes a bit longer than his.

Comment: @Adirio Ok. I'd like to see it. I'm just about to write some `timeit` code to compare the speeds of our algorithms.

Comment: @PM2Ring and Miraj50 I just added my answer. I did my timing in a different manner, getting extra stats such as median and standard deviation which timeit doesn't offer by default. Have posted it without checking the results, will look at them now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses essentially the same algorithm as Miraj50's answer, except it doesn't need a loop to calculate the length of numbers that have less digits than the current input number. I developed my formula with the help of this OEIS entry: [A033713](https://oeis.org/A033713) "Number of zeros in numbers 1 to 999..9 (n digits)".

I'll add a slightly modified version of Miraj50's code, and the brute-force version given in the comments by Blender, to show that they all give the same results.

```
def nlen_blender(n):
    return sum(len(str(i)) for i in range(1,n+1))

def nlen_miraj(n):
    length = len(str(n))
    x, s = 9, 0
    for i in range(1,length):
        s = s + x*i
        x = x*10 
    return s + (n - 10**(length-1) + 1) * length

def nlen_pm2r(n):
    digits = len(str(n))
    a = 10 ** (digits - 1) 
    return (n + 1) * digits - a - (a - 1) // 9

# test

funcs = (nlen_blender, nlen_miraj, nlen_pm2r)
data = (0, 1, 37, 563, 4285, 12900, 375462)
for n in data:
    print(n)
    for f in funcs:
        print('{:13}: {}'.format(f.__name__, f(n)))
    print()

n = 12398765434324
print(n)
for f in (nlen_miraj, nlen_pm2r):
    print(f(n))
```

**output**

```
0
nlen_blender : 0
nlen_miraj   : 0
nlen_pm2r    : 0

1
nlen_blender : 1
nlen_miraj   : 1
nlen_pm2r    : 1

37
nlen_blender : 65
nlen_miraj   : 65
nlen_pm2r    : 65

563
nlen_blender : 1581
nlen_miraj   : 1581
nlen_pm2r    : 1581

4285
nlen_blender : 16033
nlen_miraj   : 16033
nlen_pm2r    : 16033

12900
nlen_blender : 53394
nlen_miraj   : 53394
nlen_pm2r    : 53394

375462
nlen_blender : 2141667
nlen_miraj   : 2141667
nlen_pm2r    : 2141667

12398765434324
162471604969439
162471604969439
```

---

Here's a version that does `timeit` tests. As you can see, eliminating that `for` loop speeds things up, especially when `n` is large.

```
from timeit import Timer

def nlen_miraj(n):
    length = len(str(n))
    x, s = 9, 0
    for i in range(1,length):
        s = s + x*i
        x = x*10 
    return s + (n - 10**(length-1) + 1) * length

def nlen_pm2r(n):
    digits = len(str(n))
    a = 10 ** (digits - 1) 
    return (n + 1) * digits - a - (a - 1) // 9

def time_test(num, loops):
    timings = []
    for func in funcs:
        t = Timer(lambda: func(num))
        result = sorted(t.repeat(3, loops))
        timings.append((result, func.__name__))
    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print('{:13} : {}'.format(name, result))
    print()

funcs = (nlen_miraj, nlen_pm2r)
data = (0, 1, 37, 563, 4285, 12900, 375462, 12398765434324)

loops = 10000
for n in data:
    print(n)
    time_test(n, loops)
```

**output**

```
0
nlen_pm2r     : [0.03521797800203785, 0.0357760570004757, 0.035887997000827454]
nlen_miraj    : [0.0467547009975533, 0.04689033899921924, 0.04821185600303579]

1
nlen_pm2r     : [0.03615388999969582, 0.03690062500027125, 0.037922888001048705]
nlen_miraj    : [0.04778529000031995, 0.04816070699962438, 0.05409854399840697]

37
nlen_pm2r     : [0.04198674500003108, 0.04201827299766592, 0.04204300800120109]
nlen_miraj    : [0.06709170100293704, 0.067645346000063, 0.07428676299969084]

563
nlen_pm2r     : [0.04548632699879818, 0.045831783001631266, 0.04651351099892054]
nlen_miraj    : [0.0761348430023645, 0.07634904800215736, 0.08261940699958359]

4285
nlen_pm2r     : [0.04845972700059065, 0.048681981999834534, 0.04915663500287337]
nlen_miraj    : [0.08794620700064115, 0.09279651500037289, 0.0934514330001548]

12900
nlen_pm2r     : [0.04871700200237683, 0.04922142199939117, 0.050075729999662144]
nlen_miraj    : [0.09708551099902252, 0.09920390000115731, 0.12253420100023504]

375462
nlen_pm2r     : [0.05645462199754547, 0.056796938999468694, 0.05760099699909915]
nlen_miraj    : [0.1092712979989301, 0.10961470600159373, 0.11748507000083919]

12398765434324
nlen_pm2r     : [0.05949370799862663, 0.060066635000112, 0.06006887100011227]
nlen_miraj    : [0.20019025200235774, 0.20034944599683513, 0.2058156430030067]
```

These timings were obtained on my old 2GHz 32 bit machine running Python 3.6.0 on a Debian derivative of Linux.

Comment: Just to make sure, are the units in seconds? And is it giving the time for 10000 loops.

Comment: @Miraj50 That's correct. The times are in seconds. I'm doing 3 trials with each trial consisting of 10000 loops. The `timeit` docs recommend taking the minimum value of 3 (or more) trials, see those docs for the reason why.

Comment: I engulfed my code in a for loop of range 10000, and it took 0.04 seconds (2.2GHz 64 bit Ubuntu Python 3.5.2) if I remove *print* statement and replace it with  `s=s+(int(n)-10**(length-1)+1)*length`. If I print 10000 times, then it takes 0.1 sec. But anyway , *NOICE*!!

Comment: @Miraj50 I suggest you take a look at the `timeit` docs. Using `timeit` is more accurate than using `time` because `timeit` only times the code you want to test, so it doesn't include the overhead of the testing loops in its timings. Also, it disables garbage collection while it's running the tests.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Ofcourse you are! Using the timeit module, it now takes 0.03 seconds without print. With print the time starts from 0.07sec and keeps on increasing, which intrigues me? Have you noticed that the timings of Timer keep on increasing! Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Miraj50 It's difficult to get perfect timings on a multitasking OS, since there are other user programs (like your Web browser) and various system tasks using the CPU(s), and it's not really possible to correctly compensate for them. The best we can do is to do lots of loops to average out those effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158683/discussion-between-miraj50-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 0):

I found two new methods, the first uses an approach similar to Miraj50's (I was developing it while he posted so I will keep it here for the sake of completeness) in a `for` loop fashion while the second one uses vector algebra to calculate it, it may be implemented in numpy also, which may improve its performance for big numbers. You can see them as methods `a` and `b` in the folloing section.

## Profiling script

I did some timing with the following script. Modify `INPUTS` and `REPETITIONS` at will. It takes a while as it is executing `REPETITIONS * len(INPUTS)` times each method and `len(INPUTS)` times the OP's method to validate the results. It calculates the mean, median and standard deviation of the samples and print them in a nice table format. If you want to add a new method you just need to define the function and include it in the `methods` dict.

```
# Values to test
INPUTS = [7, 9, 53, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999]
# Number of repetitions
REPETITIONS = 30000

from timeit import default_timer as timer

def a(n): # Iterative method
    #n = input("Insert a number: ")
    start = timer()
    l = len(n)
    if l == 1: # Special case as int("9"*0) raises ValueError
        c = int(n)
    else:
        n, c = int(n), 9
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            if l == i:
                c += (n - int("9"*(i-1))) * i
                break
            c += int("9"+ "0"*(i-1)) * i
    print(c)
    end = timer()
    return c, end - start

def b(n): # No-loop method
    #n = input("Insert a number: ")
    start = timer()
    l = len(n)
    n = int(n)
    aux = [9*10**i for i in range(l-1)]
    aux.append(n - sum(aux))
    c = sum((v*(i+1) for i, v in enumerate(aux)))
    print(c)
    end = timer()
    return c, end - start

def c(n): # Miraj50's method
    #n = input("Insert a number: ")
    start = timer()
    l = len(n)
    x, c = 9, 0
    for i in range(1, l):
        c = c + x*i
        x = x * 10
    c = c + (int(n) - 10**(l-1) + 1) * l
    print(c)
    end = timer()
    return c, end - start

def d(n): # Pm2 Ring's method
    #n = input("Insert a number: ")
    start = timer()
    l = len(n)
    a = 10 ** (l - 1) 
    c = (int(n) + 1) * l - a - (a - 1) // 9
    print(c)
    end = timer()
    return c, end - start


# Method mapper
methods = {
           'Adirio 1': a,
           'Adirio 2': b,
           'Miraj50' : c,
           'PM2 Ring': d,
          }
methods_list = sorted(methods.keys())

# Calculate the results that are valid
results = []
for n in INPUTS:
    results.append(len(''.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1))))

# Calculate the results by the different methods
times = {}
for n, result in zip(INPUTS, results):
    t = {} # Store times
    for key in methods:
        aux1 = []
        for i in range(REPETITIONS):
            c, aux2 = methods[key](str(n))
            if c != result:
                raise ValueError("Method {} for n = {} yielded {} and {} was expected".format(key.upper(), n, c, result))
            aux1.append(aux2)
        aux1.sort()
        mean = sum(aux1) / REPETITIONS
        if REPETITIONS % 2 == 0:
            median = (aux1[REPETITIONS//2 - 1] + aux1[REPETITIONS//2]) / 2
        else:
            median = aux1[(REPETITIONS-1)//2]
        std_dev = (sum((x-mean)**2 for x in aux1)/(REPETITIONS-1))**.5
        t[key] = {
            'mean': mean,
            'median': median,
            'std_dev': std_dev,
            'min': aux1[0],
            'max': aux1[-1],
        }
    times[n] = t

# Print the results
for n, c in zip(INPUTS, results):
    print()
    print("N = {:<15}".format(n), end='')
    for method in methods_list:
        print("|{:^19}".format("Method {}".format(method)), end='')
    print()
    print("+".join(["-"*19]*(len(methods_list)+1)))
    for metric in times[INPUTS[0]][methods_list[0]]:
        print(" {:<12} [us] ".format(metric), end='')
        for method in methods_list:
            print("| {:>17.2f} ".format(times[n][method][metric] *10**6), end='')
        print()
```

## Results

```
 N = 7             |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             12.76 |             14.95 |             13.49 |             13.13 
 min          [us] |             10.21 |             12.03 |             10.94 |             10.57 
 mean         [us] |             85.15 |             87.11 |             83.93 |             85.68 
 max          [us] |          35319.77 |          37254.20 |          35428.07 |          35010.91 
 std_dev      [us] |           1486.21 |           1480.59 |           1465.55 |           1483.09 

 N = 9             |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             12.76 |             14.95 |             13.49 |             13.13 
 min          [us] |             10.21 |             12.03 |             10.57 |             10.21 
 mean         [us] |             84.94 |             87.42 |             86.09 |             85.72 
 max          [us] |          34595.95 |          35712.49 |          36281.33 |          36368.85 
 std_dev      [us] |           1485.61 |           1486.80 |           1489.28 |           1482.85 

 N = 53            |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             13.86 |             15.32 |             13.86 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             10.94 |             12.03 |             10.94 |             10.94 
 mean         [us] |             85.93 |             88.38 |             85.41 |             85.91 
 max          [us] |          34776.45 |          38539.21 |          36581.07 |          36074.94 
 std_dev      [us] |           1477.20 |           1489.63 |           1477.41 |           1485.53 

 N = 99            |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             14.22 |             15.32 |             13.86 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             10.94 |             12.76 |             10.94 |             10.94 
 mean         [us] |             88.21 |             88.46 |             86.46 |             87.04 
 max          [us] |          40802.19 |          35949.14 |          36355.72 |          39536.51 
 std_dev      [us] |           1518.92 |           1489.06 |           1488.02 |           1525.52 

 N = 999           |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             14.59 |             16.04 |             14.22 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             12.03 |             13.13 |             11.30 |             10.57 
 mean         [us] |             87.68 |             88.48 |             86.96 |             85.81 
 max          [us] |          35570.64 |          36136.57 |          42908.73 |          36164.28 
 std_dev      [us] |           1488.79 |           1482.06 |           1489.39 |           1481.22 

 N = 9999          |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             15.32 |             16.41 |             14.22 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             12.40 |             13.49 |             11.67 |             10.57 
 mean         [us] |             88.06 |             88.91 |             86.78 |             85.58 
 max          [us] |          34688.20 |          34618.92 |          35010.55 |          40569.91 
 std_dev      [us] |           1478.79 |           1473.64 |           1495.85 |           1480.70 

 N = 99999         |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             16.04 |             17.14 |             14.59 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             13.13 |             14.22 |             11.67 |             10.94 
 mean         [us] |             89.44 |             89.79 |             88.20 |             86.94 
 max          [us] |          44273.23 |          42208.25 |          40763.54 |          37936.45 
 std_dev      [us] |           1497.36 |           1482.44 |           1512.71 |           1495.37 

 N = 999999        |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             16.41 |             17.50 |             14.59 |             13.49 
 min          [us] |             13.86 |             14.59 |             12.03 |             10.94 
 mean         [us] |             88.60 |             90.63 |             87.18 |             85.68 
 max          [us] |          35199.80 |          36482.62 |          48330.99 |          51652.53 
 std_dev      [us] |           1475.87 |           1485.87 |           1483.34 |           1491.72 

 N = 9999999       |  Method Adirio 1  |  Method Adirio 2  |  Method Miraj50   |  Method PM2 Ring  
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 median       [us] |             17.14 |             17.87 |             14.95 |             13.86 
 min          [us] |             14.22 |             15.32 |             12.40 |             11.30 
 mean         [us] |             89.97 |             89.86 |             87.74 |             85.51 
 max          [us] |          35618.05 |          35605.65 |          36453.44 |          34081.07 
 std_dev      [us] |           1480.06 |           1467.89 |           1488.62 |           1475.57
```

### Interpreting results

Of the 5 measures that are being tabulated you need to be aware of some implications. As the OS's scheduler may execute different processes in the middle of an algorithm, some of the timings have a quite big error, they take way too much time that what they really needed. This means that the upper bound given by the max, or the mean and standard deviation that consider all values in the sample, give results that are not really trustworthy. Both the minimum value and the median remove the influence of this really long cases in a different way. The comparisons of the algorithms based on the median and the minimum are very similar: all of the algorithms have a similar execution time being @PM2Ring 's version slightly faster.

Comment: As explained in the `timeit` docs, there's not a lot of point calculating the median, mean & standard deviation of the numbers returned by Timer. The _minimum_ value is more meaningful. If you're _really_ keen you could do several runs with (say) 5 repetitions in each run, keeping the minimum of each set of repetitions, and then calculate median, mean & standard deviation from those minima, but even those figures should be viewed with a degree of scepticism. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring That would be in order to get something like a WCET (*W*orst *C*ase *E*xecution *T*ime), as what you are trying to do is remove every influence from the underlying system's processes, and in that case you would need to consider every posible input and get the maximum (*WC*ET) of those minimums (to remove external influences) for each case. That would be the time that the algorithm would take to run in a system where you have no more process running. The real case is a bit different as the evaluating machine will also have processes so it will suffer interferences there.

Comment: The median is a better aproximation that the mean, not as good as the maximum for every case of the minimum for multiple repetitions, but still a better aproximation and a better measure to compare one algorithm vs another as it removes some of the uncertainity while the mean just averages it.

Comment: Whatever. I'm just repeating the info given [in the timeit docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat).

Comment: @PM2Ring That does not apply to median as it is an special weighted mean based on the position in the sorted sample.